# Is there a easy method to copy Stored Process in SAS?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, sas-stored-process

I am creating 40+ Stored Processes in SAS EG (Programs already written) and I am creating Stored Processes so that end users can run them without my intervention.

Its a sloooow progress! Each SP has to be created individually. The SPs are generally all the same with a few differences (eg. program name)

Is there a copy paste or similar I can use to speed up the creation process?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using management console?

If so,

- In detail pane

  - Select one or more STP
  - Right click and choose **copy**.
- In folder pane

  - Right click and choose **paste** (can be the same folder)
  - If same folder, the new copies will get a **(#)** suffix added but have the same
    properties.
- In detail pane

  - Change properties
  - Rename to what you what
  - Change Execution property to appropriate program (already written)
  - Save

You might need to right click the folder and choose `Select` if the new entries (copies of STP) are not automatically shown.

Comment: Sadly no... SAS EG 7.13 Strangely I can copy the SP (in the Sas Folder dock) but Paste is grayed out...

Comment: Is Management Console a separate application from Enterprise Guide?

Comment: Management console is a separate administrative tool.  In EG try paste at the folder icon, not in the folder detail pane.  If that doesn't work, try pasting onto a new separate folder icon.

Comment: Management Console is often installed alongside Enterprise Guide, but not always - but odds are it's possible to install it from the EG depot, if you're not using the independent installer (I don't recall if MC is packaged along with EG's independent installer). Talk to your SAS admin, it's easy to get

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have the same issue, but the thing i do is to copy the whole sascode and paste it in new stored process and make the small changes like table name … etc, and create the inputs then finish

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Using SAS you could make use of the following macros:

- https://core.sasjs.io/mm__getstpcode_8sas.html
- https://core.sasjs.io/mm__createstp_8sas.html

But you would be much better off keeping your source code in a GIT repository and compiling / deploying your STPs as part of a release process.  By doing this you can then also easily migrate your STPs to Viya (or SASjs Server).

We built a CLI tool to enable this: https://cli.sasjs.io